# psycopg2 queries to remote database

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7, psycopg2

I need to get some data from remote database. Here code to connect:

```
import psycopg2

params = {
  'dbname': 'some_db',
  'username': 'user',
  'password': 'password',
  'host': '333.333.333.333',
  'port': 3333
}

conn = psycopg2.connect(**params)
```

Then i try to execute query:

```
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM sometable")
```

And after that i get exception:

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation sometable does not exist
```

Now if i connect to database with exact same parameters from same machine via psql:

```
psql --dbname=some_db --username=user --password=password --host=333.333.333.333 --port=3333
```

and try to execute query:

```
SELECT * FROM sometable;
```

i get results without any errors. And it happens not only with one table, but with all of them in that database.

**EDIT**

I have little mistake in params. I use not

```
'username': 'user',
```

but:

```
'user': 'user',
```

Answer (score 11):

Try connecting with different variable names, like:

```
params = {
  'database': 'some_db',
  'user': 'user',
  'password': 'password',
  'host': '333.333.333.333',
  'port': 3333
}
```

See:

http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/module.html

Comment: have you tried using a dsn string instead?  as you assert, if you can connect directly to the database with psql and you are successful, then a connection with psycopg2 with the same credentials should work about the same.